# Found unsupported keytype (8) for Principal

Tags: java, hadoop, aes, kerberos

I am using Java 7 and Kerberos to authenticate hadoop.

In the debug log I am seeing the following error:

```
Ordering keys wrt default_tkt_enctypes list
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23 18 17 16 3 1.
Added key: 3version: 1
**Found unsupported keytype (8) for hdfs/aaa.aaa@EXAMPLE.COM**
Added key: 23version: 1
Added key: 16version: 1
Added key: 17version: 1
Added key: 18version: 1
```

How to correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's a bit late, but what I've usually encountered are missing local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar files in this directory:  $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/.

Other times, it is a mis-configured krb5.ini file.